# choose amount from dropdown list - paypal

Tags: paypal

I used the following code for my Donate button. When I choose amount in dropdown list and click Donate. It redirects to paypal site and asking me to enter the amount again but I already chosen amount in the dropdown list. Any help is appreciated. thanks.

```
 <form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <select name="amount" id="amount">
       <option value="10">10 SEK</option>
       <option value="20">20 SEK</option>
       <option value="30">30 SEK</option>
       <option value="40">40 SEK</option>
       <option value="50">50 SEK</option>
    </select>
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="xxxxxxx">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" id="currency_code" value="SEK"> 
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_donate_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
  </form>
```

Comment: Using [Paypal's Donation generation button](https://www.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_donate-intro-outside), and replacing the hidden amount value with a select drop down menu works. I noticed you're using a *Buy Now* button as opposed to a *Donate* button, as indicated by your `cmd` value, `_s-xclick`. Is that intentional?

Comment: @Josh your pointer help me, thanks !!

Comment: Happy to help. Make sure to post your solution!

Answer (score 1):

When using hosted PayPal buttons you'll need to configure the drop down options in the button creation wizard.  If you want to include all of that on your own you'll need to use non-hosted buttons.